# Select <span> child from container with id and change text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change this span's text color with Javascript but I can't seem to find a way to reach it using getElementById or TagName. Is there any way to select an element where only its parent id is known?

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: better to show your code, not screen shot.

Comment: And what was so sensitive about that class-name that you had to redact it?

Comment: Use jQuery way easier. `$("#teste_1 span").css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Why not use CSS: `#banner .container .menu_banner #block_105 ul #menu_1 #teste_1 span { color: green; }`?

Comment: Well you need some way to get to the element. So somewhere you will need to use an id or a class that is relative to the element so you can "navigate" the DOM to it.

Comment: `document.getElementById('teste_1').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.color = 'green'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in vanilla JS using the `querySelector` method:

```
var span = document.querySelector('#teste_1 span');
```

Now that you've got the `span` element, you can now do anything with it (change its color, as you wanted).

The parameter for the `querySelector` is the same as how you would select the element using CSS.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelector('#test_1 span').style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `querySelector`, you can also use specialized functions:

```
document.getElementById('teste_1').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.color = 'red';
```

This is more useful if you have to get `#teste_1` separately anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to set class on span:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#teste_1 span').addClass('class_name');
});
```

Comment: The OP didn’t include the jQuery tag. This is pretty straightforward by vanilla JavaScript. Just because you have a hammer, doesn't mean everything needs to get hit!

Comment: i Hv added this "Use jquery to set class on span:-" it on him not to use the jquery...there is nothing to downvote

Comment: To the downvoters: jQuery is still JavaScript. It happens to have a good selector engine that can do what the OP asks. Would you also downvote answers that tell the OP to use other selector engines? Would you downvote any answer that tells the OP to use a certain library (with a code sample) where the OP did not specifically mention said library? I think not.

Comment: Keep in mind that answers are not just for the OP, but also for all those visitors who will randomly happen upon this question. If they are using jQuery already, an answer with it (yet still JavaScript as the tag implies) would be a valid alternative to have here it seems. Not the one the OP would select perhaps, not the one you like the best, but not necessarily problematic either unless the OP specified "No jQuery".

Comment: @Stijn Yes, I downvote all answers requiring a library on questions that aren't specific to the library. Downvoting is for answers that aren't useful, and this answer is just that.

Comment: @HashemQolami you copied that saying from me, didn't you ;)?